# How do I call the same query from the same component?

Tags: rtk-query

I have a query setup like so:

```
   ...
   doesProjectExist: build.query({
     query: (projectNumber) => ({
     url: `${URL}/exists/${projectNumber}`,
     method: "GET",
   }),
...

export const {
  useDoesProjectExistQuery
} = projectsSlice;
```

As the user selects a project, this query is called to see if it exists.

```
  const {
    data: existingProject,
    isLoading: isLoadingExistingProject,
    isSuccess: isSuccessExistingProject,
  } = useDoesProjectExistQuery(
    projectToCheckIfExists ? projectToCheckIfExists.projectNumber : skipToken
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Existing Project", existingProject);
    console.log("Loading Existing Project", isLoadingExistingProject);
    console.log("Success Existing Project", isSuccessExistingProject);
  }, [existingProject, isLoadingExistingProject, isSuccessExistingProject]);
```

The use effect spits out results 3 times, 2 of them show isSuccess = true but one has existing project as true and one with false, making it impossible to evaluate. [image: chrome console results]

If I change the query to a mutation and deconstruct the hook like so:

```
  const [doesProjectExist, { isLoading }] =
    useDoesProjectExistMutation(skipToken);
```

I can call doesProjectExist at will and unwrap the results. Is there a way to call and unwrap a query directly? Using mutation seems wrong. I feel like I am missing something easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that it's expected behavior.
The case when you have both `isLoadingExistingProject` and `isSuccessExistingProject` set to `false` - is most likely a case when you pass the `skipToken`, due to `projectToCheckIfExists` may be `undefined` during lifecycle changes.

To investigate it in a more clear way, try to do something like more straightforward:

```
const {
    data: existingProject,
    isLoading: isLoadingExistingProject,
    isSuccess: isSuccessExistingProject,
  } = useDoesProjectExistQuery(
     projectToCheckIfExists?.projectNumber, 
     { skip: !projectToCheckIfExists}
  );
```

`useDoesProjectExistQuery` may not expect `undefined` in params, but it's up to you to make it handle `undefined`, or add some null check to param like  `projectToCheckIfExists?.projectNumber ?? 0`, which will never be passed due to `skip` condition.

Not as clear as your notation with `skipToken`, but it should be more predictable.